# mySQLi query producing null values although query works outside of function

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

This one's driving me round the bend, and just can't work it out. The script works fine up until when I try to echo the final mysqli query (zen_id). I have tested the query outside of the if and while statements and it works fine. The query before it also has no troubles retrieving `$model_array['model']` and echoes it flawlessly. I don't get any errors, simply nothing is outputted. A vardump of `$id_array['zen_system_id']` gives me null, as does `$id_array`, `$result_2` also produces a large number of null values in this format: `object(mysqli_result)#5 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(1) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["type"]=> int(0) }` I think i'm probably misssing something quite obvious here I'm just lost at the moment, possibly something to do with the while function or something??

```
//Connect to Database
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "login", "user", "database");
//Check Connection
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

$result_1 = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT `product_id` FROM oc_product");


while ($rows_1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result_1))
{ 

    $product_id = $rows_1['product_id'];

    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT `product_id` FROM `oc_product_option_value` WHERE `product_id`=$product_id");

    $rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    //echo $product_id . " " . $rows['product_id'] . "</br>";

    if($rows['product_id'] == null) 
    {

        $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT `model` FROM `oc_product` WHERE `product_id`=$product_id");
        $model_array = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        $model = $model_array['model'] . "</br>";

        //echo $model;

        $result_2 = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT `zen_system_id` FROM `oc_wholesale_link` WHERE `model_id`='" . $model . "'");
        $id_array = mysqli_fetch_array($result_2);
        echo $zen_id = $id_array['zen_system_id'];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to encapsulate data which you are passing to sencond query, also, to check if query would return result you can just make an `if` condition to the fetch itself

```
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT `product_id` FROM `oc_product_option_value` WHERE `product_id`= '".$product_id."'");
if($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT `model` FROM `oc_product` WHERE `product_id`=  '".$product_id."'");
    $model_array = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $model = $model_array['model'];

    //echo $model;

    $result_2 = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT `zen_system_id` FROM `oc_wholesale_link` WHERE `model_id`='" . $model . "'");
    $id_array = mysqli_fetch_array($result_2);
    echo $zen_id = $id_array['zen_system_id'];
}
else
{
    echo 'Product Not Found';
}
```

I've changed this line `$model = $model_array['model'] . "</br>";` i just supposed `<br>` was there for debuggin purpose.

`UPDATE`

Since you only need to get products id wich doesn't exist in `oc_product_option_value` you can change the query to this

```
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT `product_id` FROM `oc_product_option_value` WHERE `product_id`= '".$product_id."'");
if($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT `model` FROM `oc_product` WHERE `product_id`=  '".$product_id."'");
    $model_array = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $model = $model_array['model'];

    //echo $model;

    $result_2 = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT `zen_system_id` FROM `oc_wholesale_link` WHERE `model_id`='" . $model . "'");
    $id_array = mysqli_fetch_array($result_2);
    echo $zen_id = $id_array['zen_system_id'];
}
else
{
    echo $product_id . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: hmm I get product not found

Comment: Perhaps im just sleep deprived but how does that help me?

Comment: This will help to understand where the problem is, the `$result` query is not working properly, change to try to print out changing to `$sql = "SELECT `product_id` FROM `oc_product_option_value` WHERE `product_id`= '".$product_id."'"; echo $sql;  $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);

Comment: but it has no issues echoing here 

 $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT `product_id` FROM `oc_product_option_value` WHERE `product_id`=$product_id");
 
 echo $rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
 echo $rows['product_id'];

Comment: I tried changing the query Im still getting a product not found error :S, this makes absolutely no sense to me..

Comment: what did the `echo $sql` output?

Comment: The right output I believe:   `SELECT \`product_id\` FROM \`oc_product_option_value\` WHERE \`product_id\`='50'`

Comment: and echo $rows['product_id']; still works fine, this is bizarre.

Comment: are you sure this product_id 50 exists in the table `oc_product_option_value`?

Comment: Well its a loop so the query actually loaded hundreds of product IDs not just 50. 

And not necessarily I built the query specifically to do that - find product IDs that do not exist in the oc_product_option_value table, thats why I had the IF null before?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28489/discussion-between-fabio-and-user1650757)

Answer (score 0):

Simple example to avoid such failure:

```
/* Select queries return a resultset */
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT Name FROM City LIMIT 10")
if (!is_null($result)) {
    printf("Select returned %d rows.\n", mysqli_num_rows($result));

    /* free result set */
    mysqli_free_result($result);
} else {
    echo "Mysqli query failed: " . mysqli_error();
}
```

Comment: This is a very bad suggestion. It keeps you safe from failures exactly the same way like an ostrich keeps itself from a danger.